# Disabling the 'Move Component' and 'Remove Component' buttons for a specific rendering in the Experience Editor based on user role

Tags: experience-editor

How can we restrict the removal of a specific rendering from the Experience Editor of any page item based on role?

My goal is to disable buttons such as 'Remove Component' and 'Move Component' in the Experience Editor and restrict the removal or moving of a specific rendering from the page item in the Experience Editor.

[image]